# Extract values from logs

Tags: unix, awk, scripting, grep, cut

Want to extract the data between the last occurrence of **[]** in the following logs.

```
[11/10/14 9:20:57:133 GMT] 000002d2 EmailAdapterE I   Processing Email :: [****][****@hotmail.com][0][1][63][4][4670][0][2014-11-24][12]
[11/10/14 9:20:57:110 GMT] 000002d2 EmailAdapterE I   Processing Email :: [****][****@aol.com][0][1][63][1][3286][0][2014-11-24][10]
[11/10/14 9:20:57:088 GMT] 000002d2 EmailAdapterE I   Processing Email :: [****][*****@pietrawoodandstone.com][1][1][63][1][3455][2000][2014-11-24][26]
```

From this i want the values between the last [] in the line.

For example from the above line... i want the following output

```
12
10
26
```

Tried `awk`, `cut` and `sed` but no success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`awk` is your friend:

```
$ awk -F[][] '{print $(NF-1)}' file
12
10
26
```

This sets the field separator to either `[` or `]`. Based on that, the penultimate field contains what you want, so that we print it with `$(NF-1)`.

Note `sed` can also make it with some regex:

```
$ sed -r 's/.*\[([0-9]*)\]$/\1/' file
12
10
26
```

This catches the last block of digits contained within `[]` and prints it back with `\1`.

With `grep` you can also use a look-behind and look-ahead to match what is in between `[` and `]` + end of line:

```
$ grep -Po '(?<=\[)[0-9]*(?=]$)' file
12
10
26
```

Comment: Some golfing: `awk -F[ '{$0=$NF+0}1'`

Comment: True! also `awk -F[ '{print $NF+0}'`